Cuantos payload tiene dhcp en bytes?
Alguien me podría ayudar cuantos payload tiene dchp en bytes, es con respecto a redes, por favor
De antemano, muchas gracias

Son 4: Discover, Offer, Request y Acknowledgment.

Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask].

y buscar eso en google no te ayudo?

no encuentro informacion

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
